# How to change the background color of an image in SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

### Context

In my SDL2 app, I am trying to load a png image(transparent). I want to give a background color to this image with SDL2 because I want to reuse the image somewhere else in the program and I do not want to have multiple version of the same image.

### Question

How to give a background color to a SDL_Surface* or a SDL_Texture* with SDL2?

### Important Details

```
OS : Windows
Text Editor : VScode
Building Mehtod : Makefile
```

### My code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);

    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;

    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(900, 500, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE, &window, &renderer);
    SDL_SetWindowTitle(window, "StackOverflowApp");
    
    SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load("./yourImage.png");
    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);

    SDL_Event event;
    bool run = true;
    while (run) {
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                run = false;
            }
        }

        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Makefile

```
all:
    @cls
    g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -std=c++23 -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image 
    ./main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

To give a background color to your transparent image, you will need to fill the image's surface with the desired background color before creating a texture from it. Here's how you can achieve that:

1. Create a new surface of the same dimensions as your image.
2. Fill that new surface with your desired background color using `SDL_FillRect`.
3. Blit (copy) your image onto the new surface.
4. Create a texture from the new surface.

Here's a modified version of your code demonstrating this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);

    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;

    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(900, 500, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE, &window, &renderer);
    SDL_SetWindowTitle(window, "StackOverflowApp");
    
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load("./yourImage.png");

    // Create a new surface with the same dimensions as the loaded image
    SDL_Surface* backgroundSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, loadedSurface->w, loadedSurface->h, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    // Fill the new surface with a color, for instance, white
    SDL_FillRect(backgroundSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(loadedSurface->format, 255, 255, 255));
    
    // Blit (copy) the loaded image onto the background
    SDL_BlitSurface(loadedSurface, NULL, backgroundSurface, NULL);

    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, backgroundSurface);

    SDL_Event event;
    bool run = true;
    while (run) {
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                run = false;
            }
        }

        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_FreeSurface(loadedSurface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(backgroundSurface);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In the above code, we create a new surface (`backgroundSurface`) and fill it with white color. After that, we blit the `loadedSurface` (your transparent PNG image) onto the `backgroundSurface`. The resulting texture will be your PNG image with a white background. Adjust the RGB values in `SDL_MapRGB` to change the background color.

Comment: Ok thank you it worked but it is strange that in the `SDL_MapRGB`, the blue and the red are reverse. What I mean is if I do `SDL_MapRGB(loadedSurface->format, 255, 0, 0)` you will have blue and if you do  `SDL_MapRGB(loadedSurface->format, 0, 0, 255)` you will have red.